# ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: typescript, webpack-5

I added the webpack 5 config like this in the typescript project:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    'index' : './index.ts', 
  } ,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
        vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../src'),
    },
  },
  output : {
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../../bundle') ,
    filename : '[name].js'
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
        },
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/js-wheel'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../src')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules|\.d\.ts$/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

but when I use this command to build the project:

```
"build": "rm -rf dist && webpack --mode development --config src/config/webpack.config.js",
```

shows error:

```
[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/xxx/source/dwarf/frontend/js/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

how to change the webpack config to support ES6? I am searching from google but did not found any clue. is it possible to transform the webpack config incompatible with ES6?

Answer (score 5):

The error shows that you are using ES module in your project, but the require are CommonJS import way, so try to using the ES module import way like this:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
```

and export like this:

```
export default {
  entry : {
    'index' : './index.ts', 
  } 
}
```