# Cannot use import statement outside a module error in addin

Tags: outlook-addin, importerror, office-addins, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I had configured **outlook** addin to **event-based activation** according to this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest
I'm trying to use my **API services** in the **launchevent.js** **file**. so
I **imported** it into the file. When I'm executing my code it shows me errors like

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**.

I don't know where I had done a mistake.I had pasted my code below.

**Can anyone guide me on this?**

lauchevent.js

```
import {update_meeting_API} from '../services/apiService'
async function onAppointmentSendHandler(event) {
  console.log("event called")
  const te = await update_meeting_API("test", "test")
}
```

commands.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
      <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../launchevent/launchevent.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

apiService.ts

```
export const update_meeting_API = async (token: String, body: Object) => {
  try {
    console.log("update meeting called")
    const myHeaders = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };

    const requesOption = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    };
    const response = await fetch(`${config.MEETING_URL}`, requesOption);
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "office-addin-taskpane-react",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-React.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "app_to_debug": "outlook",
    "app_type_to_debug": "desktop",
    "dev_server_port": 3000
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "lint": "office-addin-lint check",
    "lint:fix": "office-addin-lint fix",
    "prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier",
    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
    "validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "serve-json": "json-server --watch db.json --port 4000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.0.1",
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.52.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "json-server": "^0.17.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.318",
    "@types/office-runtime": "^1.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.4.34",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^4.1.0",
    "acorn": "^8.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-office-addins": "^2.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^10.0.1",
    "office-addin-cli": "^1.5.4",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^4.6.7",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.11.1",
    "office-addin-lint": "^2.2.4",
    "office-addin-manifest": "^1.12.0",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.2.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.7.4"
  },
  "prettier": "office-addin-prettier-config",
  "browserslist": [
    "ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please try out solution suggested [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/javascript-how-to-fix-uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when I'm changing in package.json, I can't run my add-in.

Comment: Did you change type:"git" to type:"module"? You need to add type:"module" at root level.

Comment: but type: git is for the git repository.

Comment: Yes, you need to add it at root level. not under repository. We wanted to confirm that you haven't updated the existing one which is for git

Comment: when i am defining it globally it's showing this type of error in console.
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'D:\Projects\Calloquy-Outlook-Add-in\webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'D:\Projects\Calloquy-Outlook-Add-in\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///D:/Projects/Calloquy-Outlook-Add-in/webpack.config.js:3:18

Comment: The error mentioned in the console is mostly about using import vs require, there are multiple documents for the same, one of the solution mentioned here might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71089871/referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope#:~:text=The%20error%20shows%20that%20you%20are%20using%20ES,entry%20%3A%20%7B%20%27index%27%20%3A%20%27.%2Findex.ts%27%2C%20%7D%20%7D /